How to use Newtonsoft JSON serializer for all Flurl 4.0 calls globally or per specific client
I need to use Newtonsoft JSON serializer for all calls made via Flurl 4.0 (or at least for all calls made by a specific Flurl client), but I cannot figure out how to set it up. From the answer to the FLURL 4.0 use Newtonsoft JSON Serializer on a single request question, I see how to do it for each call, but this seems a bit tedious, since I would need to use the same settings for all calls. What is the correct way to (a) set it globally (i.e. not tied to a specific client) and (b) set it for all requests made by a given client? To create a client I use the following helper method:
public static IFlurlClient Create
(
    string url,
    string? proxy = null
)
{
    IFlurlClient client = string.IsNullOrEmpty(proxy)
        ? new FlurlClient(url)
        : new FlurlClientBuilder(url)
            .ConfigureInnerHandler(h => {
                h.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy);
                h.UseProxy = true; })
            .Build();

    return client;
}

What do I need to inject into this method to make it work with Newtonsoft JSON serializer?

First install the Newtonsoft serializer from NuGet.
If you just need it to work with the client you created in your code:
client.Settings.JsonSerializer = new NewtonsoftJsonSearializer();


Clientless and DI examples are clear (I don't use DI, but I think I get it), but I'm still puzzled over the named client. FlurlClientCache and UseNewtonsoft return IFlurlClientCache object, so I assume the Newtonsoft setting will be applied to all objects in the cache. But how do I apply it to a single named client created via FlurlClient/FlurlClientBuilder in cases when I do not use client cache (as in my example) or need to have clients in the cache to use different JSON serialization configurations? Is FlurlClient missing the UseNewtonsoft method or am I missing something?

The other approaches I mentioned weren't directly relevant and may have caused confusion. Updated answer to only address your specific question.

Oh, man, this is really simple. Thanks a lot!!!
